# (Solved) Why does this Kaon interaction need the intermediate up quarks?

Tags: elementary-particles

In the answers to a set of practice questions my lecturer shows that we need these up and antiup quarks in the middle, but I don't quite understand why we can't go straight from the down to strange etc.

[image: answer to the question I am stuck on]

Comment: Hi Regan Jefferies. Welcome to Phys.SE. Note that it is against the common practice to write 'Solved' in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $W$ boson is charged, so when a d or s quarks(that have charge -1/3) emit (or absorb) a $W^+$, they must change their charges by a total of -1 (1). In order to do so, they change flavor to u/c/t, that have  charge 2/3.